# Selenium Ant build start tests in Eclipse but not in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, ant

**Running the following:** Java 1.8, selenium 3.4.0. , Ant, Jenkings and using eclipse IDE

I right click on my project and the select "Export..", under General folder then I select "Ant Buildfiles". Select your project and click finish (Ant build name = 'build.xml')

I right click on build.xml file and select ran as Ant Build.

I receive the following results:

```
> Buildfile: C:\Users\shcr\workspace\MWay_Tests\build.xml
> build-subprojects: init: build-project:
>      [echo] MWay_Framework: C:\Users\shcr\workspace\MWay_Framework\build.xml init:
> build-project:
>      [echo] MWay_Tests: C:\Users\shcr\workspace\MWay_Tests\build.xml build: BUILD
> SUCCESSFUL Total time: 429 milliseconds
```

If I right click on Build XML and select "External Tools Configuration", then under the Targets tab I can select my required tests. (Confirm your target order: "Build, tests, junitreport")If I click Run now, then it start my tests.

The problem is that in Jenkins I still only receive that build is successful but it doesn't start selenium tests:

> Buildfile: C:\Users\shcr\workspace\MWay_Tests\build.xml
>   build-subprojects: init: build-project:
>        [echo] MWay_Framework: C:\Users\shcr\workspace\MWay_Framework\build.xml init:
>   build-project:
>        [echo] MWay_Tests: C:\Users\shcr\workspace\MWay_Tests\build.xml build: BUILD
>   SUCCESSFUL Total time: 429 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Open your build.xml and add the following at the bottom of your xml

```
<target name="all" depends="build,YourTestName, junitreport"/>
```

Also make sure that default is set(the same name as your target name in this case "all") at the beginning of your build.xml

```
<project basedir="." default="all" name="MWay_Tests">
```

When I run this in jenkins now, it started the tests.

Here is my complete build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
              Any modifications will be overwritten.
              To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
              directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. --><project basedir="." default="all" name="MWay_Tests">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
    <property name="MWay_Framework.location" value="../MWay_Framework"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.8"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.8"/>
    <path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640/junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="javafaker0.1.2.userclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/javafaker-0.12/automaton-1.11-8.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/javafaker-0.12/commons-lang3-3.5.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/javafaker-0.12/generex-1.0.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/javafaker-0.12/javafaker-0.12.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="oracledriver.userclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/oracle/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="SeleniumJava3.3.1.userclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/client-combined-3.3.1-nodeps.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/commons-exec-1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/commons-lang3-3.5.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/cssparser-0.9.21.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/gson-2.8.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/guava-21.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/htmlunit-2.24.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/htmlunit-core-js-2.23.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/htmlunit-driver-2.24.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/httpmime-4.5.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/jetty-io-9.4.1.v20170120.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/jetty-util-9.4.1.v20170120.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/neko-htmlunit-2.24.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/phantomjsdriver-1.4.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/sac-1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/websocket-api-9.2.20.v20161216.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/websocket-client-9.2.20.v20161216.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/websocket-common-9.2.20.v20161216.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/selenium-java-3.3.1/lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="opencsv.userclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../../eclipse/Selenium Library/opencsv/opencsv-3.9.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="MWay_Framework.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${MWay_Framework.location}/bin"/>
        <path refid="javafaker0.1.2.userclasspath"/>
        <path refid="oracledriver.userclasspath"/>
        <path refid="SeleniumJava3.3.1.userclasspath"/>
        <path refid="opencsv.userclasspath"/>
    </path>
    <path id="MWay_Tests.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <path refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="MWay_Framework.classpath"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall">
        <ant antfile="Environment.xml" dir="${MWay_Framework.location}" inheritAll="false" target="clean"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects">
        <ant antfile="Environment.xml" dir="${MWay_Framework.location}" inheritAll="false" target="build-project">
            <propertyset>
                <propertyref name="build.compiler"/>
            </propertyset>
        </ant>
    </target>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="MWay_Tests.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="testSuiteEnvironment">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="testSuite.testSuiteEnvironment" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <jvmarg line="-ea"/>
            <classpath refid="MWay_Tests.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>


    <target name="junitreport">
        <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <target name="all" depends="build,testSuiteEnvironment, junitreport"/>

</project>
```